# Get value by click on javascript table created on the fly

Tags: javascript, select

I want to create a table with javascript on the fly and able to get all the value in the row by select that row. Currently I add a click event but it doesnt seem to work how it suppose to be.

Code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("here_table");
table.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var js = "apple";
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  tr.addEventListener('click', myFunction(i));
  td.innerHTML = js + i;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = js + 1 + i;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

function myFunction(x) {
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  alert("Value of row " + cells);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vjuwonz/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/1h4q74u2/

Comment: @Rayon In your fiddle, you used bind method, can you explain in layman how it work in this case? I am still learning javascript

Comment: If you are aware that I have used `.bind` method, why not just search about it and come with something which you did not understand ?